# How can I use shared_from_this in a derived class without superfluous RC manipulations?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

If I want to create a `shared_ptr<Derived>` in a derived class member function in a hierarchy that inherits from a base class, I can use `shared_from_this` and `static_pointer_cast`:

```
class Base: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Base> {
};

class Der: public Base {
public:
  std::shared_ptr<Der> make_SP_to_Me () 
  { return std::static_pointer_cast<Der>(shared_from_this()); }
};
```

My concern is that `static_pointer_cast` accepts its argument by lvalue-ref-to-const, so when the new `shared_ptr<Der>` is created, the reference count in the control block is incremented. When the `shared_ptr<Base>` returned from `shared_from_this` is destroyed, the refcount in the control block will be decremented again. I was suprised to see that there is no `static_pointer_cast` overload taking an rvalue that would avoid the need to manipulate the refcount in the control block.

`shared_ptr<T>` has a templatized constructor taking rvalues of type `shared_ptr<U>` that performs moves, thus avoiding the need to do refcount manipulations. Is there some reason that `static_pointer_cast` doesn't do the same thing? And is there some way for me to write the code above that doesn't involve unnecessary refcount manipulations?

Comment: Yep, all those pointer-casts should use universal references... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast A serious oversight by the committee.

Comment: @Deduplicator : BTW the new term will likely be "forwarding reference" (see some video of CppCon 2014 of Herb Sutter)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're going to have to rely on return-value optimisation and hope that it is smart enough to help you out.

If `std::*_pointer_cast` had overloads accepting forwarding references (`T&&`) then they could transfer ownership from temporaries and this would not be a problem. I consider it an oversight in the library since C++11.